# QT Tcp передача больших данных

Tags: c++, qt, сервер, tcp, client

Пишу клиент серверное приложение на QT для "копирования файлов".

Вкратце опишу работу программы:

1. Строка с директорией (куда на сервер сохранить файл)
2. Есть файл на клиенте.

Клиент должен отправлять директорию(строку) и название файла + его расширение ,тем самым создавая "оболочку файла" , а затем отправлять данные заполняя тем самым файл.

Это прекрасно работает , если всё предавать одной строкой с некими разделительными знаками , однако при больших объемах данных все данные уже не лезут в строку. Если делать луп ,то как на сервере ловить конкретно этот луп , чтобы именно в тот файл загонялись данные?

Comment: Используй http multipart

Comment: @eri , а как мне это поможет передавать данные больших объемов?

Comment: А никак:) Просто человек знает о таком и говорит.  Когда Вы вызываете запись в сокет, то функция записи возвращает, сколько на самом деле записала. И исходя из этого нужно и дописывать дальше. А если в функцию записи втулить сразу несколько мегабайт, то это точно не заработает. Точно также и на противоположной стороне - функция чтения возвращает, сколько она по факту прочитала.

Comment: @kifor4ik там в кутэ все готово чтоб получить и передать 2 строки и файл асинхронно и без костылей. Надотолько написать код

Comment: так везде - нужно только написать код:)

Comment: @KoVadim есть ещё sendfile очень классный)

Comment: Я написал код , который передает одной строкой информацию , куда и как назвать файл в который записывать. Однако естественно , что при каждом новом вызове на стороне клиента write() , я буду получать новые данные . Соответсвенно надо каким-то образом замутить так , чтобы через луп передавались данные и до определенного дела записывались в файл.  
[DIR]C:/user/username/desktop/testfolder[NAME]test.txt[DATA]ANYDATA

Comment: @eri , sendfiles ,тоже на уровне http multipart? так же поможет делу?)

Comment: @kifor4ik это по теме линукса

Comment: @eri , не , линукс не прокатит к сожалению

Comment: @kifor4ik рид-врайт в цикле тогда, только передай размер файла чтоб понять весь ли он долетел

Comment: @kifor4ik TLV тогда, если не хочешь http поднимать.

Comment: Короче говоря , я решил вопрос максимально варварским способом.
Просто вместе с данными я передаю параметры , т.е. файл у меня открыт как writeOnly + append. Т.Е. вместе с датой полезной  , передаю директорию и имя файла , тратя на это бесценные килобуты. Но с файла считываются не верные данные и поэтому всё равно gavnoi воняет ))0